# Excel mudar apenas parte de um texto da célula

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba

Em um documento excel eu quero que um determinado texto de uma célula faça enumeração automática quando faço copy paste de todo o grupo de celulas.
Exemplo da explicação.
- O que eu quero é copiar o todo o texto e que apenas me modifique a celula que diz "text,50,Num" de forma a que fique " text,51,Num" e na próxima copy paste que fique "text,52,Num" e que na proxima copy paste fique "text,53,Num".
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Explicação está na imagem. Agradecia imenso a ajuda se alguém se disponibilizasse.
 Ora eu quero uma fórmula ou algo que faça automático porque eu vou repetir esse contexto quase até ao nº 10.000.

```
sleep,1000,Delay        
tap,522,967,false,1,Tocar na mensagem       
sleep,1000,Delay        
tap,90,126,false,1,Tocar secao "a quem escrever"        
sleep,1000,Delay        
text,50,Num **Aqui onde diz 50, eu queria que no proximo copy paste ficasse 
51  De uma forma automática porque eu vou fazer até por exemplo 10,000
sleep,1000,Delay        

tap,31,55,false,1,Seta andar p/tras     
sleep,1000,Delay        
tap,522,967,false,1,Tocar na mensagem       
sleep,1000,Delay        
tap,90,126,false,1,Tocar secao "a quem escrever"        
sleep,1000,Delay        
text,51,Num ***Ficando assim 51 
sleep,1000,Delay        

tap,31,55,false,1,Seta andar p/tras     
sleep,1000,Delay        
tap,522,967,false,1,Tocar na mensagem       
sleep,1000,Delay        
tap,90,126,false,1,Tocar secao "a quem escrever"        
sleep,1000,Delay        
text,52,Num ***Ficando asim 52...   
sleep,1000,Delay
```

O que eu consegui fazer é pôr uma fórmula numa célula vazia e alterar o valor que eu quero, mas tenho que fazer isso manualmente vezes sem conta ! Existe por aí alguma forma automática ?
 Segue em anexo uma imagem do que eu consigo fazer [image: Imagem da minha tentativa falhada]

Comment: coloca o texto na pergunta para que eu consiga copia-lo

Comment: Não está claro o que você deseja fazer. Uma pergunta ampla pode ter muitas respostas distantes do que você deseja. Seja específico.

Comment: @RenatoSilva tudo o que eu quero é copiar o todo o texto e que apenas me modifique a celula que diz "text,50,Num" de forma a que fique " text,51,Num" e na próxima copy paste que fique "text,52,Num" e que na proxima copy paste fique "text,53,Num". Estou a ser claro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como seu objetivo é "Automatizar a cópia" do texto, não necessariamente no excel, fiz em C#. Basta você acessar no .NET Fiddle e copiar o resultado.

Acesso .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6uViYu

Segue o código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        for (int i =50; i <= 10000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("tap,31,55,false,1,Seta andar p/tras");
            Console.WriteLine("sleep,1000,Delay");
            Console.WriteLine("tap,522,967,false,1,Tocar na mensagem");
            Console.WriteLine("sleep,1000,Delay");
            Console.WriteLine("tap,90,126,false,1,Tocar secao \"a quem escrever\"");
            Console.WriteLine("sleep,1000,Delay");
            Console.WriteLine("text,"+i+",Num");
            Console.WriteLine("sleep,1000,Delay");
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
tap,31,55,false,1,Seta andar p/tras
sleep,1000,Delay
tap,522,967,false,1,Tocar na mensagem
sleep,1000,Delay
tap,90,126,false,1,Tocar secao "a quem escrever"
sleep,1000,Delay
text,50,Num
sleep,1000,Delay

tap,31,55,false,1,Seta andar p/tras
sleep,1000,Delay
tap,522,967,false,1,Tocar na mensagem
sleep,1000,Delay
tap,90,126,false,1,Tocar secao "a quem escrever"
sleep,1000,Delay
text,51,Num
sleep,1000,Delay

tap,31,55,false,1,Seta andar p/tras
sleep,1000,Delay
tap,522,967,false,1,Tocar na mensagem
sleep,1000,Delay
tap,90,126,false,1,Tocar secao "a quem escrever"
sleep,1000,Delay
text,52,Num
sleep,1000,Delay

tap,31,55,false,1,Seta andar p/tras
sleep,1000,Delay
tap,522,967,false,1,Tocar na mensagem
sleep,1000,Delay
tap,90,126,false,1,Tocar secao "a quem escrever"
sleep,1000,Delay
text,53,Num
sleep,1000,Delay

tap,31,55,false,1,Seta andar p/tras
sleep,1000,Delay
tap,522,967,false,1,Tocar na mensagem
sleep,1000,Delay
tap,90,126,false,1,Tocar secao "a quem escrever"
sleep,1000,Delay
text,54,Num
sleep,1000,Delay

tap,31,55,false,1,Seta andar p/tras
sleep,1000,Delay
tap,522,967,false,1,Tocar na mensagem
sleep,1000,Delay
tap,90,126,false,1,Tocar secao "a quem escrever"
sleep,1000,Delay
text,55,Num
sleep,1000,Delay
```

...Continua...

o .NET Fiddle Limitou os resultados, mas basta alterar a numeração.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64017/discussion-between-goncalo-rodrigues-and-rovann-linhalis).